# Why is float not making the text wrap?

Tags: html, css

As the following code shows, I have applied `float:left` to the image and `float:right` to the text. However, the image is still overlaying the text.

What I want is the text to be right of the image (in the starting) and bottom of the image (later). Basically, **I want to wrap the text around the image**.

```css
#intro_page p{
 line-height: 27px;
 float: right;
}

#intro_main_text{
 float: right;
}

.intro_pic1{
 float: left;
 clear: left;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="intro_page" class="unseen">
 <div id="intro_page_content">
  <p id="intro_main_text" > Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
   
  <figure class="intro_pic1">
  <img src="http://sample.com/images/freeproductsamples.jpg" alt="Sample" height="250" />
  <figcaption>Sample Image 2015</figcaption>
  </figure>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't want absolute positioning here. Can the order of the inner elements be changed?

Comment: @j08691 Yes, the order can be changed. But, removing `position:absolute` doesn't help. Even if I remove absolute positioning, and also place the figure before the text, the wrap effect doesn't happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you swap the order of your image and paragraph, you can just float the image left and reduce the CSS to:

```css
#intro_page p {
  line-height: 27px;
}
.intro_pic1 {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="intro_page" class="unseen">
  <div id="intro_page_content">
    <figure class="intro_pic1">
      <img src="http://sample.com/images/freeproductsamples.jpg" alt="Sample" height="250" />
      <figcaption>Sample Image 2015</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <p id="intro_main_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor
      sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
      adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Btw, why did the `position:absolute`  create a problem? Removing it doesn't change the position of the image, but affects the text. Why? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: When you position something absolutely you remove it from the flow of the document, so other elements act like it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks. Also, why does including `float:right` to the text mess up the wrap?

Comment: It becomes unnecessary once you float the image, but adding it forces it below the other floated element due to the rules of how floats work.

Answer (score 1):

If you move the `figure` element above the `p` element, you can simply float the `figure` element and the text will flow around it automatically. Check out [this](http://jsfiddle.net/arzds0md/) fiddle to see it in action.

And here is the modified HTML/CSS:

**HTML**

```
<div id="intro_page" class="unseen">
    <div id="intro_page_content">
        <figure class="intro_pic1">
            <img src="http://sample.com/images/freeproductsamples.jpg" alt="Sample" height="250" />
            <figcaption>Sample Image 2015</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <p id="intro_main_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#intro_page p {
    line-height: 27px;
}

.intro_pic1 {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Floats seem to be messing things up. Try this one, jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8r20z6t1/

```
#intro_page p{
    line-height: 27px;


}

#intro_main_text{

}

.intro_pic1{
    float: left;
    clear: left;

}

<div id="intro_page" class="unseen">
    <div id="intro_page_content">
                    <figure class="intro_pic1">
        <img src="http://sample.com/images/freeproductsamples.jpg" alt="Sample" height="250" />
        <figcaption>Sample Image 2015</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <p id="intro_main_text" > Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>


    </div>
</div>
```